# Division of convex functions

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, fractions

I need your expertise in understanding the following:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $i \in [n]$ and let $a \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

What can be said about the following in term of convexity (let $j$ be any arbitrary integer such that $i \in [n]$:

$$ \frac{\frac{a^2}{2n} + \max\left\lbrace 0, 1 - x_i\right\rbrace} {\frac{a^2}{2} + \sum\limits_{j \in [n]} \max\left\lbrace 0, 1 - x_j\right\rbrace} $$

I am asking this since, it's easy to see that both the denominator and nominator are convex (it resembles the objective function of SVM), however is this fraction convex, or quasi-convex, concave, etc... ?

Please advise and thanks in advance.

P.s. A more advanced question would be, what can be said on the fraction of two convex function in general?

Comment: With respect to the last question (general case), I'm not sure if anything can be said about the convexity. Take the functions $\frac{e^x}{x^2}$ and $\frac{x^2}{e^x}$, for example. I'm not so sure about quasi-convexity though.

Comment: Have you tried plotting this as a function of $a$ for, say, $n = 2, 3, 4$?  Easy to do on a computer.

Comment: Are you gonna consider this function on whole space, or you have restricted domain,

Comment: Convexity is a fragile property. It is the exception, not the rule. I frankly doubt that this is convex or quasiconvex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, consider the case where $f$ and $g$ are convex, twice differentiable functions on an interval and $g > 0$.  We have

$$ \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'' = \frac{f'' g^2 - 2 f' g g' - f g g'' + 2 f (g')^2}{g^3} $$

and the condition for $f/g$ to be convex is that the numerator is always nonnegative.  Unfortunately, not a very nice condition!

Comment: $x^2\over e^x$ satisfies those conditions and is concave for $x \in (2- \sqrt2, 2+\sqrt2)$?

Comment: $x^2/e^x$ is convex for $x^2 - 4 x + 2 \ge 0$, namely for $x \le 2 - \sqrt{2}$ and $x \ge 2 + \sqrt{2}$.  It is concave for $2-\sqrt{2} \le x \le 2 + \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Ah nevermind - I misinterpreted 'numerator' to be $f$ rather than the RHS of the above.